# How do I integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\!\sin x^2\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How do I integrate 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\!\sin x^2\,dx?
$$
Will it be so complicated?

Comment: The function $\sin(x^2)$ does not have an elementary indefinte integral. You need to use Taylor series of $\sin$ or some other numerical method. Have you covered that in class? The series will be an alternating sum, so estimating the cut-off error will be easy.

Answer (score 11):

This integral is known as the [Fresnel Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral), defined by:

$$S(x)=\int_0^x \sin(t^2) \, dt$$ 
And cannot be evaluated without the use of a series approximation.
Numerically, this is around $0.31$.