# Evaluation of certain definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

How do we integrate the following two integrals? 
$$ \int_{-e}^\pi \cos(-3x^2) \, dx$$ and $$ \int_{-e}^\pi \frac {e^x}{\ln(a-x)} \, dx,$$ where $a>\pi$.

Comment: For the first one, take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433448/how-do-i-integrate-int-01-sin-x2-dx/433453#433453 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: Maple by $J := int(cos(-3*x^2), x = -epsilon .. Pi)$ produces $$1/6\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }\sqrt {3}{\it FresnelC} \left( {\frac {
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}\epsilon}{\sqrt {\pi }}} \right) +1/6\,{\it FresnelC
} \left( \sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }\sqrt {3} \right) \sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }
\sqrt {3}
 $$ and $ series(J, epsilon, 3)$ gives $$1/6\,{\it FresnelC} \left( \sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }\sqrt {3} \right) 
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi }\sqrt {3}+\epsilon+O \left( {\epsilon}^{3}
 \right) .

 $$

Comment: The Maple command $$series(int(exp(x)/ln(a-x), x = -epsilon .. Pi), epsilon, 2) assuming a > Pi $$ performs $$\int _{0}^{\pi }\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{x}}}{\ln  \left( a-x \right) }}{dx
}+{\frac {\epsilon}{\ln  \left( a \right) }}+O \left( {\epsilon}^{2}
 \right) 
 .$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-e}^\pi\cos(-3x^2)~dx$

$=\int_{-e}^\pi\cos3x^2~dx$

$=\int_{-e}^\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(3x^2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}dx$

$=\int_{-e}^\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n9^nx^{4n}}{(2n)!}dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n9^nx^{4n+1}}{(2n)!(4n+1)}\right]_{-e}^\pi$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n9^n(\pi^{4n+1}-(-e)^{4n+1})}{(2n)!(4n+1)}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n9^n(\pi^{4n+1}+e^{4n+1})}{(2n)!(4n+1)}$

$\int_{-e}^\pi\dfrac{e^x}{\ln(a-x)}dx$

$=\int_{a+e}^{a-\pi}\dfrac{e^{a-x}}{\ln x}d(a-x)$

$=\int_{a-\pi}^{a+e}\dfrac{e^ae^{-x}}{\ln x}dx$

$=\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\dfrac{e^ae^{-e^x}}{x}d(e^x)$

$=\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\dfrac{e^ae^xe^{-e^x}}{x}dx$

$=\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\dfrac{e^ae^x}{x}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^{nx}}{n!}dx$

$=\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^ae^{(n+1)x}}{n!x}dx$

$=\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^a(n+1)^kx^{k-1}}{n!k!}dx$

$=\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^a}{n!x}dx+\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^a(n+1)^kx^{k-1}}{n!k!}dx$

$=\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\dfrac{e^{a-1}}{x}dx+\int_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^a(n+1)^kx^{k-1}}{n!k!}dx$

$=\left[e^{a-1}\ln x\right]_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}+\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^a(n+1)^kx^k}{n!k!k}\right]_{\ln(a-\pi)}^{\ln(a+e)}$

$=e^{a-1}(\ln\ln(a+e)-\ln\ln(a-\pi))+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^a(n+1)^k((\ln(a+e))^k-(\ln(a-\pi))^k)}{n!k!k}$